# Почему не получается удалять подряд элементы из середины Carousel?

Tags: c#, uwp

В Carousel отображается коллекция объектов, которые мне нужно добавлять/удалять, если удалять элементы с конца или начала, то удается удалить больше одного элемента подряд, но если удалять из середины, то получается удалить только 1 элемент, как я понял, Carousel обновляется только если я сдвину выбранный элемент, как можно это исправить? Пробовал Carousel.UpdateLayout() но не сработало:

Page.xaml:

```
        <controls:Carousel x:Name="ClipboardsCarousel"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Margin="0,0,0,35"
                           ItemRotationX="0" ItemRotationY="35" ItemRotationZ="-5"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Clipboards}"
                           InvertPositive="True" 
                           ItemDepth="250"
                           ItemMargin="25"
                           Orientation="Horizontal"
                           SelectedIndex="0">
            <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
            </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>

            <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ClipboardModel">
                    <StackPanel Background="#1F1F1F" 
                                BorderThickness="1.8" 
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}"
                                CornerRadius="8"
                                Padding="15"
                                Width="250"
                                Height="350">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="18"
                                   Margin="0,2,0,16"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"
                                   MaxHeight="270"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource ShadedTextColor}"
                                   />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Carousel>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
        private void ConfirmDeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int currentIndex = ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedIndex;
            viewModel.DeleteClipboard(((ClipboardModel)ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedItem).Title);


            if (ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedIndex == viewModel.Clipboards.Count)
            {
                ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedIndex -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedIndex = currentIndex;
            }

            ClipboardsCarousel.UpdateLayout();

        }
```

ViewModel:

```
        public ObservableCollection<ClipboardModel> Clipboards { get; set; } = 
            new ObservableCollection<ClipboardModel>
        {
        };

        public void DeleteClipboard(string title)
        {
            ClipboardsDatabase.DeleteClipboard(title);
            RefreshClipboards();
        }
```

Comment: Этот код работает или не работает? Ошибка возникает? Какая именно? В какой именно строке? Что значит "подряд" несколько за одну операцию или по одной за несколько операций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обновляете данные, но пытаетесь работать с контролом до того как он подтянет изменения, ведь UI поток все еще занят обработкой вашего кода.

Получается, что хронологически вы сначала игретесь с индексом выделенного элемента, а потом только контрол обновляет данные, в результате чего индекс выделенного элемента слетает.

Можно воткнуть вот такой некрасивый костыль, показываю для наглядности проблемы.

```
private async void ConfirmDeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int currentIndex = ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedIndex;
    viewModel.DeleteClipboard(((ClipboardModel)ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedItem).Title);

    await Task.Delay(1);

    if (currentIndex == viewModel.Clipboards.Count)
    {
        currentIndex--;
    }
    ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedIndex = currentIndex;
}
```

Ну или добавлять обработчик события, вызываемый при смене выделенного элемента и обрабатывать поведение там.

---

А вообще надо использовать привязки данных `x:Bind` или `Binding`, тогда можно было бы через `SelectedItem` этим всем управлять без костылей. А чтобы не мучаться с клик-обработчиками, используйте команды `ICommand`, тогда код, обрабатывающий клики будет тоже во вьюмодели.

Получится что-то вроде такого во вьюмодели

```
public ClipboardModel SelectedClipboard { get; set; } // +INPC реализация

public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
{
    var index = Clipboards.IndexOf(SelectedClipboard);
    Clipboards.Remove(SelectedClipboard);
    if (index == Clipboards.Count);
        index--;
    SelectedClipboard = Clipboards[index];
}, parameter => SelectedClipboard != null);
```

```xaml
<Button Content="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
<controls:Carousel SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClipboard}" .../>
```

А `SelectedIndex="0"` надо вообще убрать, при наличии привязки `SelectedItem` оно само заработает так как вам надо.

Кстати, привыкайте все-таки использовать `x:Bind`, оно бодрее работает и в некоторых случаях удобнее использовать.

---

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но мне помогло добавление этого ифа в конец:

```
private void ConfirmDeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    if (viewModel.Clipboards.ToList().Count != 0)
    {
        ClipboardsCarousel.SelectedItem = viewModel.Clipboards[currentIndex];
    }
}
```